# Linux and Windows EFI - Not enough space

Tags: linux, boot, grub, arch-linux, efi

I already have Windows installed on my machine, and I'm trying to install an EFI boot manager such as Grub, rEFInd, or gummiboot on Arch Linux. Whenever I try to install any of these three options I eventually come to an error related to `efibootmgr`.

The output of efibootmgr shows:

- My Windows boot entry
- Hard Drive boot entry
- CDROM boot entry

In addition, the output also says that it doesn't have a BootOrder, which may or may not be relevant to the issue.

When I try to create a new boot entry with `efibootmgr`, I get some variant of the error "not enough space" in, what I'm guessing, would be the NVRAM on the motherboard.

An option I have seen so far is to boot the kernel along with the parameter `efi_no_storage_paranoia`. However, this seems dangerous as I don't want to risk bricking my motherboard.

In summary, I'd like to seek an answer on how I can free up "space" that `efibootmgr` is saying that it's missing. I have already deleted unnecessary entries in `efibootmgr` from previous installations. I am sure that it is *not* in any way related to there being insufficent space in the ESP partition `/dev/sda2`, as `du -sh` outputs it total disk usage as 51M(b).

Comment: EFIs do "garbage collection" to make deleted space actually available. If this hasn't happened recently, it could explain your problem. Usually, rebooting will trigger this garbage collection operation, so that's worth trying. If that doesn't help, you could look through `/sys/firmware/efi/efivars` in Linux for unusually large entries that might be deleted; however, I don't recommend deleting anything until you know what it is and can be certain it's not required.